# Angularjs ng-options for an object

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have a form that collects information such as a singer's first and last name, 2 guitarists first and last names and a drummer's first and last name. I'm attempting to push these values into select tag with ng-options.

I can successfully get in the guitarists names to show up in the select drop down, but I can't seem to get the singer and the drummer to show up.

```
<select ng-model="band" ng-options="band.firstName for firstName in band"></select>

$scope.band = {"singer": {
  "firstName": "Dave",
  "lastName": "Grohl"
  },"guitarists": [
{
  "firstName": "Chris",
  "lastName": "Shiflett"
},
{
  "firstName": "Pat",
  "lastName": "Smear"
}],"drummer": {
"firstName": "Taylor",
"lastName": "Hawkins" }};
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rfT7f/17/

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ngOptions`, you have to use a consistent object (or array) structure like

```
$scope.band = [
    {
      "firstName": "Dave",
      "lastName": "Grohl",
      "role": "singer"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Chris",
      "lastName": "Shiflett",
      "role": "guitarist"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Pat",
      "lastName": "Smear",
      "role": "guitarist"
    },
    {
      "firstName": "Taylor",
      "lastName": "Hawkins",
      "role": "drummer"
    }
];
```

Then you can do cool things like group options together in your select:

```
<select ng-model="bandMember"
    ng-options="artist.firstName group by artist.role for artist in band">
</select>
```

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention your `ngModel` should point to where you want to store the selected option, in this case $scope.`bandMember`

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the structure I have to work with.  Is it possible to copy the first and last names for each into another array? and use that instead?

Comment: Absolutely, using lodash or underscore, add this to your controller: `$scope.artistList = []; _.each($scope.band, function(artist, role) { if (_isArray(artist)) { _.each(artist, function(member){ $scope.artistList.push(member);}); } else { $scope.artistList.push(artist) } });` then use `artistList` as your `ng-options`

Comment: I'm attempting to implement this, but it's not cooperating. I've added underscore but I'm still getting an error.http://jsfiddle.net/K94Hz/1/

Comment: Two things, I was missing a `.` in my code, should be `_.isArray` and you forgot to update your select tag to `<select ng-model="bandMember"  ng-options="artist.firstName for artist in artistList"></select>`. http://jsfiddle.net/K94Hz/3/